# why can't commit and push on sourchtree?

Tags: git, github, push, vuetify.js, atlassian-sourcetree

I use gitlab (https://github.com) to store my repository data and I use sourchtree tools (https://sourcetreeapp.com) to pull, commit, push etc.

from this reference: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start, I run `vue create my-app` to install the required files

after installing, I want to commit and push to the repository on GitHub. so I did a few settings. from sourcetree, I choose new->add existing local repository and choose my project folder. then I choose the repository menu->repository settings->remotes and set it like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCnv0.jpg)

the installed files should be detected there. but they did not appear. so I can't commit.

if I change a file, it is detected, but the installed files are not detected. This is very strange

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean that newly added files are not included in commits?
If so, you should try to add the files to version control before committing. In a terminal window, this would be accomplished using the "git add" command. In Sourcetree, use the Stage File option, as described here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/get-started-with-sourcetree/commit-and-push-a-change-git-847359114.html

Comment: @IvanKrizsan I know that. if I modify the code, it is detected. My problem is that when I run `vue create my-app`, the installed files don't appear

Answer (score 0):

> I run vue create my-app to install the required files...after installing, I want to commit and push to the repository on GitHub.

This is pretty typical of `git` in general. If I create a new file in a git repository on my machine and then run `git status`, the new files shows up as an untracked file. In order to get `git` to start tracking the file, I have to run `git add <filename>`. After that, I can commit the file.

Similarly, if I change a file that's already being tracked, `git` notices that the file has changed, but it doesn't automatically add it to the list of files that will be committed; I have to again `git add <filename>` to add it to the upcoming commit.

You seem to expect `vue create ...` to add the new files to the repo for you. I don't use `vue` so I can't speak to what it does, and perhaps there's an option to automatically add the files to your repo, but that's not typical of interactions with `git`. `git` expects you to be explicit about what you want to commit — you have to add each change that you want.